# How to pre-load JS files?

Tags: javascript, html, optimization

So I have a website, that has a configurator, where you can configure your own product. The configurator website needs additional `.js` files, like `dist.js` and `libs.js`. Both of those files are around 2mb's each.

My question is: how can I start downloading those files on the landing page, so that when user goes to `/configuration.html`, he already started downloading those files?

Comment: Simply embed them, so they'll be downloaded, and ensure they're cacheable…?

Comment: Why your JS file so large? Can you trim it down / compress it / remove useless stuff?

Comment: http://blog.xebia.com/http2-server-push/

Answer (score 0):

You need define the file in your HTML:
    `<script src="yourfilename.js"></script>` Be sure to put .js at the end otherwise it wont work.